# Displaying Totalamount

Tags: reactjs, mern

Want to display total amount on the screen. I'm getting amount as gettran.amount for single transaction but i want totalamount to be shown on screen. Learning Mern, till now i can fetch the transactions details,add transaction, delete transaction ,but now i want to show the analytics btw im making expense tracking app

```
     import React from 'react'
import { useState } from 'react';
export default function TranItem(props) {
    const{gettran}=props

    const [transactions, setTransactions] = useState([]);
    

    const deletetransaction=async (id)=>
    {
        const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/api/transaction/deletetransaction/${id}`, {
            method: "DELETE",
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
              "auth-token":localStorage.getItem('token')
            }
          });
         const json=await response.json()

         const newTransactions = transactions.filter((transaction) => transaction._id !== id);
         setTransactions(newTransactions);
  };

    
  return (
    <>
     <div className='col-md-3'> 
         <div className="card my-3">
        <div className="card-body">
            <h5 className="card-title">{gettran.type}</h5>
            <p className="card-text">{gettran.amount}</p>
            <p className="card-text">{gettran.tag}</p> 
            <p className="card-text">{gettran.date}</p> 
            <i className="fa-solid fa-trash mx-2" onClick={()=>{deletetransaction(gettran._id)}}/>  
            <i className="fa-solid fa-pen mx-2"/>  
        </div>
        </div> 
        </div>   
         
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about you fields in array of transactions, but `.reduce()` is what you need.

This approximately what you need to do if your store contains array of transactions:

```
const sum = transactions.reduce((acc, {amount}) => {
  acc = acc + amount;
  return acc;
}, 0)
```

Diving deeper - you need to refetch transactions list to be sure your data is consistent, not to delete it from array.